# How to draw a 3D plot of a function which have two parameters with complex parametric values?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, complex

I am trying to draw the 3D figure of the function 1+e^{px+qy} with the complex parametric values p=1+i and q=2-3i. Actually, I am trying to draw a 3D figure of a function of the form f(x,y) = e^{ax+by}, corresponding to the complex parametric values for a and b.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your function reduces to a complex number for most values of x and y. If you want to do a plot, you need to decide whether you want the real/imaginary parts, absolute value, etc. For example, to plot the real part, use Plot3D[Re[<your function>], {x,xmin,xmax},{y,ymin,ymax}] and similarly for the other choices. Since you ultimately calculate pixels positions, you need to generate real numbers in order to choose pixels on your screen.

Comment: It is customary to provide feedback. You can accept the answer that helps you the most by clicking the checkmark next to the answer of your choice that will turn green. Search engines prioritize pages with accepted answers so the page gets more visibility.

Answer (score 2):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

p = 1 + I;
q = 2 - 3 I;

f[x_, y_] := E^(p*x + q*y)

Manipulate[
 Plot3D[func[f[x, y]], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -2, 4},
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {x, y, func}),
  PlotLabel -> Style[StringForm["`` = ``",
     HoldForm[f[x, y]], f[x, y]], 14],
  ClippingStyle -> None],
 {{func, Re, "function"}, {Re, Im, Abs, Arg},
  ControlType -> RadioButtonBar}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
p = 1 + I;
q = 2 - 3 I;
ComplexPlot3D[1 + E^(p Re[z] + q Im[z]),
 {z, -4 - 4 I, 4 + 4 I}]
```

[image]